# Umbraco - Page Not Found

Tags: .net, umbraco

I have set up and installed Umbraco 6.1.6 which works perfectly on localhost. I have to use 6.1.6 as my server only has .NET 4 installed.

However, after publishing the files to my server The [Homepage works](http://autoupdate.charleshurstgroup.co.uk/IT/default.aspx), but the links to the other pages don't. Logging into the Umbraco back end, everything seems to work as expected, except again when I try to preview a page then it cannot be found.

I have tried re-publishing the entire site, and I have also ensured the pages have a template chosen.

Has anyone any clue as to what is going wrong?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple level 0 pages or are the subpages children to the homepage?

```
HomePage
SubPage
SubPage
SubPage
```

If so, you have to move the subpages to be children of the homepage.

```
HomePage
-- SubPage
-- SubPage
-- SubPage
```

I hope this solves your problem. :-)